# When does password expire when unchecking "Password never expires"

Tags: active-directory, password, user-management

On a Windows Server 2008 R2 AD, if you uncheck the account option "Password never expires" on a User Account, does the password expire instantly, or does it get set to the period defined in the Password Policy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expiration date should be inherited from the domain's policy. The last password modification date is being stored in the attribute *pwdLastSet*

So if you uncheck the box there's a slight chance that this user's password is older then your policy defines. Therefore the password might expire.

But you can check password expiration with

```
net user username
```

Edit: I think I just found the solution you are looking for. Just set pwdLastSet to -1 and it will store today's date.

Source with a decent VBS script: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5556806/change-password-expiration-date-in-active-directory-using-vbs

Answer (score 0):

You could also use Powershell as well as dism for this purpose. 
https://www.itechtics.com/set-windows-local-user-account-passwords-to-never-expire/

And yes the option will take effect immediately. If you uncheck the option, it will abide by the group policy no. of days before the password expires.